# PHPMailer body message empty error

Tags: phpmailer

using tutorials I pasted and filled the following PHPMailer php file and made the following html form. However after send the error appears "Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Message body empty". Please help.

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'xxx@gmail.com';                 
$mail->Password = 'xxx';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587;                                    

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('xxx@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  



$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->Body    = $message;



if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}

?>
```

and here is the form

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="email.php">

    <div class="input-text-container clear">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name"   
     class="input-text input-text-left">

    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" 
    class="input-text input-text-right">
    </div>

    <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your     
    Message" class="textarea"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" value="submit Form" class="submit">SUBMIT</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script seems to rely on request parameters being available as global variables. But this is a very uncommon (and insecure) practice.

Use `$_POST['message']` instead `$message` and the message body should contain data from the form. Do the same for the other parameters.

Comment: thanks, I did it for all parameters, now I can see both, the body and the name, however the e-mail for response does not show up anywhere, do you know how this aspect may be fixed?

Comment: Currently you use both, the attributes (`From`, `FromName`) and the method to set them (`setFrom()`). The one overwrites the other, so the address `from@example.com` will not be present in your e-mail any more.

Comment: sorry for my confusion. That from@example.com it seems that I don't need at all, because I need to know the e-mail, which is written in the form. If I delete the setFrom(), it still does not show me what is the e-mail, which has been written in input cell with ID "email"

Comment: Whichever way you set the From address, don't use the submitter's address as the from address - it's forgery and will cause you to fail SPF checks. Put your own address in From and add the submitter's address as a reply-to using `addReplyTo()`.

Comment: @Huselius How about appending it to the message body?

Comment: thanks, but how do I link addReplyTo() with the e-mail, which user indicates in "email" field in the form?

I tried $mail->addReplyTo(); and $mail->addReplyTo = $_POST['email']; , but they did not work

Comment: `$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);`

Comment: I'm ready to accept it, but what should I press? This was my first question in stackoverflow.